# Adobe Air Android Debug

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I am using Flash Builder 4.6 to develop an Android game using Air. When I debug on PC it works fine, however when I plug in my Android phone and attempt to debug, I get an error with the location of a db file.

This is what I presently have the location set to:

```
private static var DefaultDB:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("com/arakaron/Assets/Database/DefaultDb.db");
```

What / where should I be setting it to? It seems that when I debug the app, nothing gets transferred to the phone as I can't find any Arakaron resources on the phone.

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the DB in this way.

Please use below code.
File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("DefaultDb.db");

Your db has to be within the application storage. If you want to have inside the folder then you define the folder name like below:
File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("db\DefaultDb.db");

Answer (score 0):

The `File.applicationDirectory` on Android refers to your application and assets. On Android this is contained packaged in your APK and assets are decompressed in memory by the OS when you access them. You shouldn't use this directory unless you are reading assets from your package. Assets in this directory can only be accessed via a `url` and won't have a `nativePath` property.

Most likely you should use the `File.applicationStorageDirectory` or if the files can be safely deleted without breaking the operation of your application you should use the `File.cacheDirectory`.

You can read more on these locations: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7fe4.html

If you package a database with your application you should use the File copy process to copy the file to one of the above locations before attempting to access it as a database.

Comment: I'm not OP, but that was an interesting read. I will take it into account in a current project. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Im not trying to access the defaultDB for use as a database. My game logic is that it will search for the local copy (applicationStorageDirectory) of the db file which is where all of the users application data is stored. If this file does not exist, then the game will create a copy of the defaultDB. This works properly when I debug on the PC but as soon as I debug with an Android phone attached the debugger stats it cannot find the file (defaultDB). Thus my dilema, so where can I go from here? The defaultDB is packaged with the rest of the application, so what can be done

Comment: I'm an idiot. I got this to work. Turns out it had nothing to do with the defaultDB location, but however the location of where I was trying to copy the file to. I was trying to copy it to documentsDirectory on a phone, which doesn't work. All good. Thanks.